# jQuery change cell class and update data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table in my page as below.

```
<table id="tbl">
  <tr>
    <td class="field" id="field1s">field1x</td>
    <td class="field" id="field2s">field2x</td>
    <td class="field" id="field3s">field3x</td>
    <td class="field" id="field4s">field4x</td>
    <td class="xx">#</td>
    <td class="yy">#</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The texts of fields in row change into inputs on `<td class="xx">` field and get updated on next click. This works fine. But I want the class `xx` change to `aa` and `yy` to `bb` when user first click `<td class="xx">#</td>`. Then the field may change to inputs, enabling user to change text. If user again click `<td class="aa">#</td>` (previously `<td class="xx">#</td>`), the text in row may be updated and if user click `<td class="bb">#</td>` (previously #), the row may go back to previous state. (Just like OK and CANCEL).

[**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/QtLXG/1/) is the fiddle.

How can I do this? I prefer a simpler and faster solution.

Comment: Do you want to cancel changes on clicking cell with blue background?

Comment: @Adil I have some other functio with blue cell. Thats irrelevant for the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to keep your classes, try [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/QtLXG/3/).

I've used event delegation [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to keep consistency with your class changes.

The `.toggle` should be removed to prevent some bugs - e.g. in thecodeparadox's answer, if you click the edit button followed by cancel button, the next click in the edit button will fire the wrong function.

Just don't forget to replace `.live()` by `.on()` if you're using jQuery 1.7+ in your page.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery [**`.data()`**](http://api.jquery.com/data/) you can solve it easily. I think you don't need to change class.

```
   $('#tbl .xx').toggle(
      function() {
        $(this).siblings('.field').each(function(){
          var t = $(this).text();
          $(this).data('prev', t);
          $(this).html($('<input />',{'value' : t}));
        });
      },
      function() {
        $(this).siblings().each(function(){
          var inp = $(this).find('input');
          if (inp.length){
            $(this).text(inp.val());
          }
        });
      }    
    );


    $('#tbl .yy').click(function() {
      $(this).siblings('.field').each(function(){
            $(this).text($(this).data('prev'));
       });
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8rVxc/)**

Comment: Just want say +1 for `.data()`. (min 30 char limit so)